# Retornar pesquisa de banco de dados com Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou tentando pegar o conteúdo nome de um input da minha pagina de pesquisa (Pesquisar), e enviar para outra view (Dados), onde o controller irá receber este valor e a partir daí irá buscar no banco de dados as informações relacionadas com este nome (Ex: id, nome ou sexo), assim ele irá preencher os inputs da view "Dados", porém não estou tendo sucesso. 
Segue o código do meu controller:

```
public function search(User $request)
{
    $nome = $request->input('teste');
    $users = DB::select('select * from users where nome = ?', $nome);*/
    return view('users.index')->with('id', $users->id);
    return view('users.index')->with('sexo', $users->sexo);
    return view('users.index')->with('idade', $users->idade);  
}
```

Ou seja, oque estou tentando fazer é que a View "dados" receba as informações da pesquisa SQL do controller, relacionadas com o nome que foi posto no input da pagina de pesquisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function search($request)
{
    //pega o valor do campo teste
    $nome = $request->get('teste');
    //busca o primeiro usuario com o nome passado
    $user = DB::select("select * from users where nome = $nome")->first();

    //retorna a view users.index passando as variaveis nome e user
    return view('users.index', compact('nome', 'user'));
}
```

Na sua view users/`index`.php:

```
{{ $user->id }}
{{ $user->sexo }}
{{ $user->idade }}
{{ $nome }}
```

Comment: Este "User" é o controller, model ou request?

Comment: seria sua model, mas atualizei a pergunta utlizando `DB::select` para ficar mais facil